# What does the abbreviation "con" mean in the following context?

Tags: abbreviations

I have no idea what *con* means reading through [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973629/fneron).

> Pro : Java, Design patterns, Quick learner (API, SDK, etc.), PHP, Javascript.
>
> Con : C++ skills for gaming industry
>
> Love : Challenge!

Comment: He has two lists, called "Pro" and "Con" ... humorously proposed as things in his favor and things against.

Comment: @GEdgar Well, I don't think that was his intention. I prefer not to interpret it in the context of _pros and cons_.

Comment: @GEdgar I guess _Pro_ means proficient while _Con_ might mean conversational, both of which indicate the degree of skill proficiency.

Comment: As an American, I would never use *pro* and *con* for *proficient* and *conversational*.  However, that guy is in Sherbrooke, so maybe his native language is French, and he used them in a way unfamiliar to me.

Comment: @TerryLi: There is basically no chance *Con* means conversational in that profile. Every answer and every comment here is telling you that this *con* means *against*, just like it always does in "pros and cons", no matter what your preference. Clearly, the author is trying to be humorous or playful. The only uncertainty is which direction he meant to go with his joke.

Comment: @JohnY I'm convinced.

Comment: You could maybe just ask him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Pro* is Latin for "for"; *contra* is Latin for "against". *Con* is simply short for *contra* (a single syllable to match *pro*).

For those who want a dictionary, this is OED:

> **con**<sup>10</sup>:
>   *adv.* An abbreviation of the Latin prep. *contra* ‘against’, in the phrase **pro-and-con** v.   (q.v.) ‘for and against’, rarely **con and pro.**
>   *n.* The adv. used as a name for itself; hence, a reason, argument, or arguer against, esp. in **pros and cons.**

In the context of the CV quoted, it's essentially meaningless. It might mean that he's actually no good at C++, which is unlikely; or it might mean that having used C++ in gaming he's not much use for anything else; or something else.

Comment: It's not meaningless, but it is ambiguous. Maybe he is also confused about the meaning of "con" or is trying to force a play on words by saying that he's a real "pro" at Java. Where that leaves C++ I'm not really sure. C++ is for hacks and con means with?

Comment: hmm... maybe it is supposed to mean contra or against...how peculiar--In that case, yes, meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually an abbreviation

Look at entries for pros and cons under either *pro* or *con* in a dictionary.
Where pros are the good things about someone or something, cons are the qualities that get in the way.

upside/downside
[advantage/disadvantage](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/pro)

Comment: I don't agree, but let's see others' input.

Comment: @TerryLi this is the normal use of pro and con. I agree, it does not make much sense in the profile you linked to but the user could merely be expressing himself badly. See, for example, [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pros+and+cons).

Comment: I think Adam is correct (+1).  There is no other (sensible) interpretation. I think the profile is being facetious: my interpretation is that he is saying he has `C++ skills for gaming industry`, but he does not consider these to be an asset. Perhaps he didn't like a previous position that used those skills; the gaming industry is known to be pretty full-on as a work environment.

Comment: I wasn't really paying much attention to what he was listing so much as I was the definition of the field label--It did strike me as a bit odd that both were in the singular (i.e., *pro* instead of *pros*). Still, it's not an abbreviation so much as it is wordplay or plain confusion. Maybe the user also speaks Spanish and is treating *con* as if it meant *with* for the sake of being silly.